# Very simple example about a button in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, button

I want a very simple button with some explanation/vizual-thing, perhaps onCreate/onLauncher to do what makes you smile! I have tried buttons [here](http://pastie.org/5189178) but errs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekk9R.jpg), probably easiest if someone could direct me to a ready working example about a button in Android. History shows problems with R and XML -files, probably easiest if someone could state it clearly how to do it: a very simple button. Its directory tree etc?

**Please, provide a simple example about a button in Android, nothing else.**

> [image]

Comment: I think you have build a java project, not an android project.

Comment: I simplified the question so people see it clearly what I am trying to do: this is probably just a few lines of code. No black magic, keep it simple! You can see my trial in the urls above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's take a look at your [`test.java`](http://pastie.org/5189178), it won't work as is. I hope you understand basic concepts of object-oriented programming and get rid of the static methods.

In Android there's a class called [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) which you need to extend. If you followed [Lazy Ninja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225086/83047), [the Eclipse plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) might have already created that one for you (it may be called `MainActivity.java`). Simply put, an activity represents a view in your application. In your trivial example, most if not all, your code goes to that class.

In Android, you don't use `public static void main(String[] args)`, but override the activity's [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method. In the [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) you define your activities (at this point you only need one) as well as which is the one launched when your application starts, and whose `onCreate` is the starting point of the whole app (again see the structure created by the Eclipse).

In `onCreate` you should call [`setContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) with the layout you wish to use in that activity. The layout is given to the `setContentView` as an integer parameter from the generated R class, like `R.layout.layout_file_name` which maps to the XML file at `res/layout/layout_file_name.xml`.

The layout file is the one that contains the declaration of the desired layout. In your case, it might have a [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) as the root element and two [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)s.

Comment: What should I do [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BkDmz.png)? I haven't been able to go forward from this point, cannot understand what it is doing so always skipped the activity thing. I use API 10 2.3 for dev because I have a phone of that version.

Comment: Just select `None` as the `Navigation Type`.

Comment: You should always use the latest API as the `targetSdkVersion` and set the `minSdkVersion` to the lowest you want to support. The Eclipse plugin will bug you if you try to use something not supported on the minimum version. These properties are defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in [`<uses-sdk>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: Trying to get a small demo working with sound [here](http://pastie.org/5342888). Cannot yet understand the setContentView, taking some time. Anyway +1 for helping, have to read some documentation to put them together.

Comment: The `setContentView` is where you programmatically say that this is the layout I want to use with this activity. The integer parameter you provide is an identifier generated by the framework that refers to the layout file. See [the resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) for further details about accessing different resources from the `R` class.

Comment: Now it looks much better. But, see the [UI events guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) on how the set the `b1` and a click listener on it. I suggest you keep this question for getting the desired layout implemented and set up another one for further development.

Answer (score 4):

Go into the xml for the buttons and set an onClick attribute of "runClient".

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="runClient"
        android:text="=)" />
```

### UPDATE:

You should see something like this in eclipse.

[image]

### UPDATE 2:

This is an example android project file tree. Highlighted is where the layout.xml should be.

[image]

Comment: Updated my q, do I need to create some XML -file to Src? Like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cDBVU.png)? I cannot yet understand how my code will refer them? Do I import them similarly to packages?

Comment: That photo in the link above does not seem to be an Android Project. I updated my question to show an example Android Project file tree.

Answer (score 2):

In your main activity use something like this:

```
//Part of onCreate
Button b1;
setContentView(whatever.it.is);
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonID);

b1.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);

//Outside of onCreate, on its own
Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener  = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Switch statement so you don't have to use a lot of click listeners
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.b1:
                doSomething();
            case R.id.b2:
                doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
};
```

In your XML when you implement the button make sure to add this:

```
android:id="@+id/anID"
```

Change anID to the id you want.

Also I prefer IntelliJ (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for Android programming. Your XML should be in a folder titled 'res' then in a subdirectory 'layout'. If you don't see those folders your project might not be set up correctly.

Comment: Where do you refer which XML -file you use or do I actually need any XML -file? Does there exist good defaults for buttons?

Comment: I still think the main problem is that the hhh doesn't seem to have an Android Project.

Comment: @EGHDK I have now but I cannot understand XML at all, I like this code here though +1 -- now trying to fill the gap between this and the xml. I cannot understand whether the XML -things work like Java -packages or something else?! Do they work like objects with methods or something else? Pretty lost in reading the xml: how are referenced from the source code?

Comment: Your layouts in Android may appear to be "drag and drop" but are actually done in xml. This is a MAJOR thing to comprehend and I wouldn't move on until you understand it. If you want some more help, please post a picture of your file tree. As you can see in this answer. @GLaDOS also refers to XML. This is crucial.

Comment: For some added help try looking here [Android Developer Website XML Help](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Answer (score 2):

On eclipse

1. Click File -> New -> Other, a dialog will pop up.
2. From the dialog, select Android -> Android application project and
   hit next.
3. A New Android Project dialog will popup, fill Application, Project
   and packages names Chose SDK version
4. Follow the wizard until you click Finish

There you will have your android project file. And you layout xml file will be the res -> layout folder.
I think you should read [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) to get you start.

Answer (score 2):

Answer step by step to your question :

1. Mostly, XML file store in the /res folder where you can define
   the interface of Android UI. For example, if you have 2 activities in your app, you can create 2 xml files ( layout of an activity ) represent of that 2 activities.
2. In the /src directory is just for java file. XML file should be created in the /res/... directory.
3. Each view of XML file has an id. When you first create an android project. the main activity already set a content view of your first app using method of Activity Class.

   **setContentView(R.layout.main)**

-layout - represent layout folder in the /res folder
-main - represent an XML file in the /res/layout folder.

You can find out more with [android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: I cannot fully understand this, puzzle 3 in updated q where I have tried to follow the instructions but I get the irritating error about missing R?! Not yet understanding the loading of the XML element.

Comment: Does your R.java missing or not ? **myButton1** is a Button view not a layout view. **setContentView** is a method to set the layout view of an activity.

[http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/10/27/3361246/asdfasdfas.png](http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/10/27/3361246/asdfasdfas.png)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make a button, or any other Android GUI is with REBOL 3:

```
REBOL [] 
load-gui 
view [button "Click Me" on-action [request "" "Clicked!"]]
```

That's a fully functioning GUI program, with all the power of the core REBOL language available to do networking, list processing, text parsing, file managment, etc.  That program, and any other for R3 will run on Android AND on desktop OSs, using the *exact same* code.  Take a look at:

http://rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&permalink=Nick25-Aug-2013/10:08:38-7:00&archiveflag=new

Answer (score 0):

It looks like with your updated information and code that you are not initializing the button properly.

There is no need for this line:

```
setContentView(myButton1);
```

What setContentView(); does is it sets the xml view.

```
Button myButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

The above line is what is really good for you. You now can use:

```
myButton1.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

Button.OnClickListener buttonListener  = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Switch statement so you don't have to use a lot of click listeners
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.myButton1:
                doSomething();
            case R.id.b2:
                doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
};
```

Also the code you have set up is not an Android setup. You are using

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Which you don't want in an Android project. Please watch some videos on how to setup this appropriately. This line:

```
Button myButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Has an error because 'R' is not something your IDE knows right now because the project is not set up correctly. Once you do so a lot of your problems will be fixed. You would be running it instead of through main(String[] args), on onCreate() etc... And again I highly recommend IntelliJ, it makes it really easy to setup an Android project, even more so than Eclipse.